# Grub2 config & nvidia driver updates

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, kernel

I have a few issue with my Ubuntu 22.04.3 configuration. Every few months I am prompted to update my nvidia drivers, and without fail it will black screen after the install. I go through removing the installed drivers, adding the repository, and installing the nvidia supported drivers for my card manually. I am then able to boot into the GUI. I have an RTX 3050.

While dropping into recovery mode for the above monkey patching, I noticed I have 2 kernels in the boot menu. I have `6.2.0-1014-gcp` and `6.2.0-33-generic`. I cannot get login GUI (or terminal) from the `gcp` kernel. This release mentioned google cloud platform configuration - should I have this kernel on a home tower installation?

Currently, every reboot is defaulting to that `gcp` kernel and it is hanging at:

```
Loading Linux 6.2.0-1014-gcp ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

I see that entry in the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but I'm not familiar with what needs to be done to fix / remove, etc.

My goals are:

1. Stop the software update center from updating my nvidia driver with whatever version is causing nvidia driver failure & black screens.
2. Configure my current working nvidia driver to update semi-regularly.
3. Fix the `gcp` kernel, or remove it from the grub menu.